# Excel: Import files using VBA and name sheets after file name that is too long

Tags: excel, vba

I have adapted a code I found on here, which pulls in text files and pastes the data into new sheets. This file is supposed to name the sheets the name of the text file, but my text file names are too big. It seems excel sheets can be 31 characters long. How can I adjust this code to name the sheets using the first 31 characters of the text file names?

I would also like for the code to prompt me to pick the folder destination. I've tried a few things, but haven't figured it out yet.

```html
Sub ImportManyTXTs_test()
Dim strFile As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
strFile = Dir("I:\path\*.lev")
Do While strFile <> vbNullString
Set ws = Sheets.Add
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & "I:\path\" & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = strFile
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlYMDFormat, 1, 1)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(22, 13, 13)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
strFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Name = Left(strFile, 31)`

Answer (score 2):

Change `.Name = strFile` to

```
If Len(strFile) < 31 Then
   .Name = strFile
Else
   .Name = Mid(strFile, 1, 31)
End If
```

Comment: SteJ below suggested the same. It doesn't seem to be working. An example file name is "1015584_OW174-35_2015_06_22Compensated.lev"

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LEFT()` function to only get the first 31 characters of your filename, like so:

```
Sub ImportManyTXTs_test()
Dim strFile As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
strFile = Dir("I:\path\*.lev")
Do While strFile <> vbNullString
Set ws = Sheets.Add
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & "I:\path\" & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = LEFT(strFile,31)
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlYMDFormat, 1, 1)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(22, 13, 13)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
strFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out how to get it to prompt for a folder location, but neither of the above suggestions worked. The sheets are still getting default labels.

```html
Sub ImportManyTXTs_test()

Dim foldername As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Show
  On Error Resume Next
  foldername = .SelectedItems(1)
  Err.Clear
  On Error GoTo 0
End With


Dim strFile As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
strFile = Dir(foldername & "\" & "*.lev")
Do While strFile <> vbNullString
Set ws = Sheets.Add
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & foldername & "\" & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = Left(strFile, 31)
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlYMDFormat, 1, 1)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(22, 13, 13)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
strFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
' using for each loop

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
       ws.Rows("1:45").NumberFormat = "@"
       ws.Rows("1:45").Replace _
       What:="=", Replacement:="", _
       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
    Next

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(16, 2).Value) Then
    ws.Name = ws.Cells(16, 2).Value
    End If
    Next
```

I managed to solve my problem by adding this to the end of my code. My data files have a header which unfortunately uses a lot of "=" making excel import those items as equations. The instrument name is in the header which is what I want the sheets to be labelled.

Not sure why naming after file name wouldn't work.